# PHP Encoding type

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I have problems with encoding csv file and showing it.
I found function like:

```
$row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen("1611005286991218.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            //echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
        }
```

And it's opening but not encoded. This is the first lines of output:

> PK!��Y^�[Content_Types].xml
> �(����N�0E�H���-Jܲ@5��*Q>�ēƪ_��{&.-�V���J
> [�dM���J���r5���Lҽ`>�蛃�����1GLx��gѣ֭��^S�|����A:<��R�"���t�E
> !�I�wV�N�ޒRx��˹�g.�e� ��PK!�E��O_rels/.rels
> �(���MO�0��H�����ݐBKwAH�!T~�I����$ݿ'\�Jcp��׏_y���Q9�^��uQ�bg�����R?��@�D��(�5�8®���>�H)Ů�Qe5t)�{�h:�(���J#a���Т'3P˸)�[�5�Zh�����T}�y����4��1��]:�yN�
> ە�-�>_�j
> -' V�SNG$ �#m����8q"K��H��@���i���/��$�"�'.ޠz��PK! Go��xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels �(��R�j�0��b�촔R"�R
> ���im�ؒ�n��
> Bz�eavٙ��v�3���+��zl�;���b���G��ۛ��s�>�� �8��

I tried encoding it with UTF-8, but no success, like so:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($data[$c], 'UTF-8', 'windows-1251');
```

Anyone had similar problems?

Comment: That's not a CSV file you're opening, and that's not an encoding problem. That's an XLSX file, which is basically a ZIP file full of XML files.

Comment: So what do I have to do?

Comment: One of the ways: please put the XLSX file to a PC (with excel installed) and save the file as CSV , upload back to server then retry.

Comment: Or use a lib like PHPexcel that can read the files.